# Python change the length of a bytearray

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to copy the contents of one bytearray to another in python, however my code `bytearray1[:] = bytearray2`, however this doesn't work. Is it because I initialised the second bytearray with `bytearray2 = bytearray()`, and therefore `bytearray2` is empty? if so is there a way to initialise it and then dynamically change the length to an integer of my choosing? Thanks!

Comment: What does it mean that it doesn't work? Also, it's a lot easier if you just post your code

Comment: Perhaps you meant `bytearray1 = bytearray2[:]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `bytearray2 = bytearray()` will create an empty byte array.

When you assign with `bytearray1[:] = bytearray2` it copies the value of bytearray2 (i.e. nothing) to bytearray1.

This works perfectly on my machine, and leaves me with 2 empty bytearrays.

What were you expecting to happen?

---

Regarding your second question:

```
b = bytearray()
b = bytearray(100)
```

will first create an empty byte array, and then create a bytearray of length 100, initialised to 0. It may or not be the same object, but as python lacks pointers it has the intended effect.

Comment: my bad I just double checked my code and I had it the wrong way round :) thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

python works on references
I am not sure what you are trying to do and if this is the best way to do it :) 
maybe you should post some of your code.

Regardless the answers you seek maybe be deepcopy. 
if you want to go down this path i would check copy and deepcopy to be sure what you are doing.
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/copy.html